# using bitbucket-pipelines deploy same branch to multiple environments

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-cloud, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I have three environments is AWS dev/uat/prod, and the same branch(develop) I wanted to develop in all three respective environments using `bitbucket-pipelines`. As I know we need AWS `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` to do so.

My question is: how to provide AWS `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` for all the three environments dynamically?, 
I am able to deploy at time on one environment as of now.

Thanks for help in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of client libraries that allow you to parametrize AWS credentials without having to store them in the environment-specific config files. You didn't specify what AWS service you want to use, but here's and example for S3: [s3_website](https://github.com/laurilehmijoki/s3_website)

Their config file looks like this; you can configure multiple sets of variables.

```
s3_id: <%= ENV['S3_ID'] %>
s3_secret: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET'] %>
```

If this doesn't work for you, write a shell/python script around AWS CLI and pull the environment-specific variables into AWS config file yourself. Manage that script as part of your source code or a [docker image](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-do-I-create-a-docker-image-for-Bitbucket-Pipelines/qaq-p/334724).